# Is there a history/log file for QGIS DB Manager?

Tags: qgis, postgis, dbmanager

When using PostGIS through psql I can look back through the commands I've run in `~/.psql_history`.  Is there any equivalent log/history file for when I'm connected through QGIS DB Manager?

I've started looking at the [source code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/db_manager/dlg_create_index.py) But haven't yet found the answer!

For reference I'm running QGIS 3, PostGIS 2.4, PostgreSQL 10 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS 3.2, there is a history of queries on the right panel.
[image: DB Manager history]

Comment: This is useful - and I do us it... but I still can't `grep` it...